# how to get value of a select box in custom widget wordpress

Tags: widgets

I am trying to make a custom widget. My codes are as follows:

```
class techno_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(

    'techno_widget', 

     __('Recent Full Post', 'techno_widget_domain'), 

    array( 'description' => __( 'A full post will be appeared on Sidebar', 'techno_widget_domain' ), ) 
);
}

public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
$blog-title = $instance['blog-title'];

echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

echo $instance['blog-title'];                   

echo $args['after_widget'];
}

public function form( $instance ) {
if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
$title = $instance[ 'title' ];
}
else {
$title = __( 'New title', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
}

$blog-title = $instance[ 'blog-title' ];

?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blog-title' ); ?>"><?php  _e( 'Select Title:' ); ?></label> 
<select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blog-title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'blog-title' ); ?>">

<?php  

                $fullpost = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',                      
                ));

if($fullpost->have_posts()): while($fullpost->have_posts()): $fullpost->the_post(); ?>

    <option value="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></option>

<?php endwhile; endif;?>

</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php 
}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}

function techno_load_widget() {
register_widget( 'techno_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'techno_load_widget' );
```

Now wordpress show an error. It tells,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\wpexperiment\wp-content\themes\lawyer\functions.php on line 87

Whats wrong with my code? How can I get the value of my select box?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ending curly brace of the class `techno_widget`, you need to call the function `techno_load_widget` outside of the class `techno_widget` and you declared the variable '$blog-title`wrong. You can't declare variable with`-`. It is core` PHP` convention. So I rewrite your code like below-

```
class techno_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(

            'techno_widget',

            __('Recent Full Post', 'techno_widget_domain'),

            array( 'description' => __( 'A full post will be appeared on Sidebar', 'techno_widget_domain' ), )
        );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $blog_title = $instance['blog_title'];

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

        echo $instance['blog_title'];

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        }

        $blog_title = $instance[ 'blog_title' ];

        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blog_title' ); ?>"><?php  _e( 'Select Title:' ); ?></label>
            <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'blog_title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'blog_title' ); ?>">

                <?php

                $fullpost = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                ));

                if($fullpost->have_posts()): while($fullpost->have_posts()): $fullpost->the_post(); ?>

                    <option value="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></option>

                <?php endwhile; endif;?>

            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
}
function techno_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'techno_widget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'techno_load_widget' );
```

And that was working. Here is the screenshot-
[image]

Now you can modify this code as you wish. But I think where you used `$instance['blog-title']`(in my code that is `$instance['blog_title']`) there may be you could use `$instance['title']`.

And you can get the input as getting input form any other input fields. For further information please google it.

Comment: Yes, There were some syntax error. But the problem which I mentioned is not solved still now. "echo $instance['blog_title'];" in widget function does not work. It does not show anything. @the_dramatist

Comment: Use `$instance['title']`. Hope that's gonna work.

Comment: Yes, Its working but both of them showing the same widget title :-D :-D I am not getting blog post title. I want to get value from the select box. Do you have any Idea about that?

Comment: I already told in the answer. Look that. Your widget `select` input works as any other HTML input. Just do some google you'll get your answer. And for post title you need to run query for that.

Comment: @KallolDas, if this answer helped you, would you please consider to accept it ? It would be very helpful.

Comment: Actually I didnt get my answer which I was seeking for. You corrected some other faults but could not answer the question exactly. For this, I can give you a lot of thanks but cannot  accept the answer.